# Is there another way do do this?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I intended to write a code that allows for input of names in some sort of an array or rather list but could not figure out how to so I went with a code that allows for input of names in the form of a string which I then convert into an array. Is there another way? If so please help… I’d also like to know how I can get rid of those commas at the end of my output list of elements.

```
NSLog(@"Enter the names: ");
NSFileHandle *input = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [NSData dataWithData:[input availableData]];
NSString *inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
inputString = [inputString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *list=[inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

 for (NSUInteger i = list.count; i > 1; i--) [list exchangeObjectAtIndex:i - 1 withObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)i)];
NSLog(@"Shuffled list is: %@",list);
   return 0;
```

Below is how my output appears:

```
2017-11-07 15:46:57.448280 inputAcc[971:35071] Enter the names: 
diana,eunice,hanifa,patricia,sitna,fiona,anita
2017-11-07 15:47:49.813347 inputAcc[971:35071] Shuffled list is: (
    diana,
    sitna,
    patricia,
    eunice,
    anita,
    hanifa,
    fiona
)
```

Comment: _"Is there another way?"_ ...to do what, exactly? Explain your desired input format more clearly.

Comment: to input elements of an array without first resorting to a string as I have done...my desired input format is to declare an empty array which I can then fill with some input elements.

Comment: All input is a string.

Answer (score 0):

> to input elements of an array without first resorting to a string as I have done...my desired input format is to declare an empty array which I can then fill with some input elements

Are you trying to read the input a line at a time and stop when there is no more input? If so then there is no standard Objective-C framework method to do this, they provide instead GUI and bulk file-oriented I/O routines, you need to construct your own.

Here is one simple way, there are others. Objective-C is built on C, the standard C libraries are available, and those libraries have character & line oriented input functions. A suitable function for your purposes is `fgetln()`, which reads at most a single line of input returning a pointer to the first byte and a count of bytes. You can turn this into an `NSString`, removing the trailing newline, if any:

```
// MINIMAL read line, lacks proper error checking etc.
NSString *readLine()
{
   size_t count;
   char *inp = fgetln(stdin, &count);

   if (inp == NULL) return nil;

   // remove any trailing newline from count
   if (count > 0 && inp[count-1] == '\n') count--;

   return [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:inp
                                  length:count
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Using the above you can read lines up to an empty line using something like:

```
NSMutableArray *list = [NSMutableArray new];
NSString *line;

NSLog(@"Enter the names: ");
while( (line = readLine()) && line.length > 0 )
   [list addObject:line];
```

> I’d also like to know how I can get rid of those commas at the end of my output list of elements.

Those commas are simply the way `NSLog` formats your output. If you wish to produce a different result format the array yourself. Look up methods such as `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:`, and if you do not want `NSLog`'s time stamps look up the C output functions such as `printf()`.

HTH